# ASP.NET MVC : Empty ActionLinks appearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using a default route, so that I don't need to specify the controller.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{action}/{id}", 
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With this, I can create URLs like myapp.com/Customers rather than myapp.com/Home/Customers

When I test locally, everything is fine. When I upload a live version, any links generated with Html.ActionLink are empty. I know I'm using Html.ActionLink correctly, because it works fine locally:

```
//                   Title                 Action      Controller
<%: Html.ActionLink("Manage My Settings", "Settings", "Home") %>
```

I've removed all routes but the default, tried specifying ActionLink with and without the controller etc. I even tried reverting to having the controller in the route, e.g:

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Nothing works live. Everything works locally. Going slightly mad.

**UPDATE:**

OK, made a strange discovery. I actually had another optional UrlParameter after id, called page. I stupidly didn't include it in the example because I thought it made no difference. If I take it out, things seem to work.

So, actually, this works:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", 
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and *this* works!

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", 
   "{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but *this* does *Not* work

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", 
   "{action}/{id}/{page}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
    id = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Why Not?

Comment: on wich version of IIS you have been deployed application the same as localy?

Comment: IIS6 on the server, and locally its whatever internal server Visual Studio 2010 runs, which I believe is IIS 7.5

Comment: this is the problem look in my answer below

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. Routing has worked just fine on this app. its only the Html.ActionLink() that's causing a problem

Comment: ActionLink generate urls but problem in routing

Comment: are you trying other url for example <%:Html.ActionLink("some","Register","Account") %> this link would not work on local I think you should change your routing

Comment: Has it ever worked on IIS6 before? Before you dismiss Serghei's answer you should follow those steps. MVC doesn't work on IIS 6 out of the box.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "empty"? Do the links look like this?

  <a href="">Manage My Settings</a>

Comment: @Serghei: actually that would work, as I have another controller called Account =) but I will try a non-existant one and see what happens

Comment: dismissile: the server its running on has already been set up to run a number of MVC apps, which work fine.

Comment: ɹǝʇǝd: that's correct, exactly like that

Comment: just updated... I had an extra UrlParameter which I stupidly forgot to mention...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer! There's a bug in MVC3 when using two consecutive optional UrlParameters, as detailed by Phil Haack, here [routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx)

You need to first declare a version of the route with only one optional parameter. So

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{action}/{id}", // URL with ONE parameter
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
    id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default_with_page", // Route name
    "{action}/{id}/{page}", // URL with TWO parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
    id = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    // Parameter defaults
);
```

Seems really obvious now. If I'd actually included all the details I'm sure Serghei or someone else would have seen the problem, so thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: O M G. Thank you so much. I spent an hour trying to figure this out. I thought it was caused by a sub domain.

Comment: This helped me too. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782089/html-actionlink-not-working-in-production-environment/26024843

Answer (score 1):

look at the article in which is explayned [how to deploy ASP.NET MVC Application on IIS6](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/)