# Html.ActionLink not working in production environment

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, iis, razor

I'm currently working on an MVC4 project, that is being deployed to an `IIS6` hosting environment.

---

I am using `Html.ActionLink()` to generate links on my page.

eg:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home Link", "Index", "Admin")
```

When I run the application locally (ie hitting `http://localhost:yyy`), the link is generated fine:

```
<a href="/Admin/Index">Home Link</a>
```

When I run it in the production environment however:

```
<a href="">Home Link</a>
```

As you can see, the link does not have a `href` generated for it.

---

I thought it might be an issue with routing, but when I try to visit a page in the browser: `admin/edit/45`, or one using a custom route binding: `sf/24`, both of these work fine; they direct me to the page I expect.

---

I'm pretty out of ideas, and not sure on how to resolve.

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

---

I've added a bounty to this, in the hope that it might help get an answer. I suspect this problem could help others, as I don't seem to be doing anything too groundbreaking.

---

**UPDATE 24/09/14**

This is being developed in VS2010 SP1, using the built-in web server (Cassini?).

I am then publishing (using the in-built options of Visual Studio) to the server, which is running IIS6.

The directory structure contains something similar to:

```
App_Start
Assets
Classes
Content
Controllers
DomainModel
Scripts
Services
SharedAssets
ViewModels
Views
```

(ie. nothing in there matches the names of any links).

On top of this, bundling seems to work. eg: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/adminjs")`

Using this (VB) Razor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "Display", "Form", New With { .id = 72 }, Nothing)
<br />
@Html.RouteLink("View", "Default", new with { .controller = "Form", .action = "Display", .id = 72 })
```

I get the following output..

In VS10/Chrome (local):

```
<a href="/Form/Display/72">View</a>
<br>
<a href="/Form/Display/72">View</a>
```

In IIS6/Chrome (server):

```
<a href="">View</a>
<br>
<a href="">View</a>
```

..adding more to the mystery of it not picking up the routes..

Comment: are you hosted site as a virtual directory?

Comment: No, the site is hosted as an application within IIS

Comment: is this the root site?

Comment: There are other sites on the server, but access to 'index' is through http://xxxx/, and not http://xxxx/yy

Comment: I've had a similar issue before, what does the file structure look like within your deployment folder?

Comment: Are you also developing locally in an IIS6 environment, rather than IIS7?  I had all manner of problems trying to redeploy from one to the other.

Comment: First try change the `@Html.ActionLink(...)` to `@Html.RouteLink("Home Link", "Default", new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" })` and see if anything changed. It can help us make better guess on where the problem is.

Comment: I've updated my answer with findings from these examples. Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your route configurations?

Comment: It seems there is a problem with RouteValueDictionary when it is hosted in production based on the source code: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/LinkExtensions.cs

I would investigate further on this. Hopefully I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911471/asp-net-mvc-empty-actionlinks-appearing) to see if you are experiencing the same issue regarding the way that your routes and default routes are defined.

Comment: Following one of the answers in this post has lead me to be able to  partially resolve my issue, I shall now investigate to solve the problem fully.

When I used a "simple" route (with only one optional parameter) it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIS 6 does not support app-pools with Integrated mode. [Here is a guide](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETMVC/216_Hosting_and_Deployment_of_an_ASPNET_MVC_Application_in_IIS6_and_IIS7.aspx) to how you can get IIS to route the requests to your ASP.NET MVC application. [More guiding here.](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-asp-net-mvc-under-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-classic-mode---solution-to-routing-problem)

[Here is a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/716067/1764737) comparing the two modes, Classic and Integrated.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm struggling to see if this is the problem though.

When I directly access the page (eg `/admin/edit/72`) the expected page displays and works.

What doesn't seem to be working is the actual generation of these links.

Comment: Ok, then these things are not connected. Strange stuff.